# Dynamic Linq and substitution values with unknown number?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic-data

Typically a dynamic linq query with string can use a substitution value such as:

```
result =
    db.Persons.Where("Name == @1", "John");
```

I have an unknown number of strings that I want to pass into the `Where` clause. I have no problem with integers, but the API cannot seem to handle a string without a substitution value.

Does anyone know a way around this? I created a concatenated string for my `Where` statement, so I can add "@1" or whatever, but I cannot add parameters to the `Where()` so I am stuck. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I creating a concatenated string for my where statement, so i can add "@1" or whatever, but I cannot add parameters to the Where() so I am stuck.

Yes, you can. The second argument of the `Where` method is `params object[] values`, so you just need to pass an array of objects.

For instance, assuming you have the property names and values in a dictionary, you could do something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Name", "John" },
    { "Age", 30 },
    { "City", "New York" }
};

...

var conditions = dic.Keys.Select(
    (key, idx) =>
        string.Format("{0} == @{1}", key, idx));
string predicate = string.Join(" And ", conditions);
object[] values = dic.Values.ToArray();
result = db.Persons.Where(predicate, values);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I can see what you mean about the string substitution problem.

Here are a couple of alternatives to explore. Thomas Petricek's solution, if you can follow it, is especially interesting:

**Building [Dynamic] LINQ Queries at Runtime in C#** 
http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx

**Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates using PredicateBuilder** 
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

---

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2006/05/10/594966.aspx

Comment: Seriously?  In 2011 this is the best there is for getting an or'd condition?  Oh the lulz, well albahari at least looks understandable.  I thought for sure there would be something better than this by now.

Answer (score 2):

I have made something for this.  Using David Fowlers DynamicLinq project in combination with a PredicateBuilder you can build predicates from a Generic IQueryable and build them.  Special thanks to some StackOverflow answer that gave me this line to convert from

```
Func<dynamic, dynamic>

to:

Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

Implmentation..

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFuncTbool<T>(IQueryable source, Func<dynamic, dynamic> expressionBuilder)
{
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetElementType(source), expressionBuilder.Method.GetParameters()[0].Name);
    DynamicExpressionBuilder dynamicExpression = expressionBuilder(new DynamicExpressionBuilder(parameterExpression));

    Expression body = dynamicExpression.Expression;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameterExpression);
}
```

This allows "or" joining generic Predicates in a loop like this...

```
predicateToAdd = query.DynamicWhereForPredicateBuilder(z => z[columnName].Contains(dataTablesRequest.sSearch)); //contains or
```

The full write up is [here](http://www.ranessoftwareconsulting.com/articles/reusable-dynamiclinq-with-predicatebuilder-to-search-every-column-of-jquerydatatables) and the full demonstration is in the source at [MvcCms.CodePlex](http://mvccms.codeplex.com/)