# What's the best practice in executing a stored procedure with multiple parameters using MVC3?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am working at implementing a search feature into my MVC3 application. I'm looking to pass two parameters into and execute a stored procedure that will look basically something like this:

```
create procedure MyProc
(
@FirstParam nvarchar(50),
@SecondParam nvarchar(20)
)
as select * from MyTable where @FirstParam like @SecondParam
```

- MyTable has about 30 fields that will be returned for each object and I need to create a procedure like this for several tables, so I am trying to avoid using a SqlDataReader and  converting the returned Sql data to C#.
- I would like to use something like [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-4-1-using-stored-procedure-to-insert-data.aspx) but I am not sure if this can be done with multiple parameters.
- Ideally I would like to use EF4, but I have not found any good information on executing stored procedures while using EF4.

Any insight on the most painless way and/or best practice for executing this task will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to keep common cases out: You model is already in EF4? SP is the only solution or can you take another approach?

Comment: Yes, the model is already in EF4. I'm open to any method. I have free reign over this project. The "LIKE" clause is the only must.

Comment: +1 for the "free reign".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sugestion is use [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937435/dynamic-linq-and-substitution-values-with-unknown-number), and [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)). You can pass valid linq expressions as regular strings:

```
var column = "Name";
var value = "Marvin";
var query = DbCtx.MyEntity.Where("{0} == @1", columnName, value);
```

The benefits (IMO) is that you can keep the search logic in the application and, if you need to do this for many tables, you can create a T4 template to generate the bootstrap code for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting *can* indeed be done through parameters, and you *should* be using an ORM like EF4 for you data access. Like most ORM that have support for stored procedure, you *can* indeed pass multiple parameters to the stored procedure.

The issue you will find, however, is that you can't have dynamic column names in SQL Server (or any other SQL database that I am aware of) - you can't give a column name in a variable.

You will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to achieve this, either within the stored procedure or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to take some time and get familiarized with dynamic SQL, but for now I guess I will use EF to pull in the entire table and then use a switch case for the FirstParam field, which would mean only passing in one parameter that can then be filtered using linq.